# Can't see anything printed

Tags: python, loops, printing

Could you help me to understand why can't have anything printed?

```
list = [1, 2,3,4, 5, 7, 9] 

def test(list):  

    # Using for loop 
    for i in list: 
            d = i % 2
            if d == 0:
                print('odd')
                save = i + " it's odd"

            else:

                print('even')
                save= i + " it's even"

            return save
    print(save)
```

Comment: is this your full code? are you calling your function passing your list as an argument?

Comment: This isn't a working example.  Python will error out immediately when trying to concatenate an int and a str.  Please give us a working example that shows your issue.

Comment: Yes. I know it's awkward but I'm trying to learn python by myself and making some experiences. Mark, it doesn't returns any error (using spyder)

Comment: @Krauss, your code sample above does raise an error. `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'` - this is because you are trying to concatenate a string and an integer. Please make sure that you provide a [minimum reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) example. You also should avoid using the names of built-in types, like `list`, as variable names as this can cause issues.

Comment: dspencer, thank you for your reply. As I said, spyder doesn't return any error (see for yourself). Will follow your advice. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you, let me know if it doesn't. Here's a couple of pointers on your code above:

1. in the line **save = i + " it's odd"** and **save= i + " it's even"** you are trying to add a string and an int -- python doesn't really like this and will throw an error. But you can use .format method to insert values into a string. Here's a link with some examples https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-format-function/
2. The return will end your function. So the way you have it will only let the for loop get the first index in the list. (index 0). So for your purposes I would just go ahead and ditch the return call.
3. You call your list "list", which is intuitive-especially if you are just starting out. But python has built in functions that you can call on and one of them is list. It is a good idea to think of these as "reserved words" and to not use them as variable names. Try something like "lis" or "my_list" instead. Here is a link to some built in python functions that you will see a lot. https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html
4. Lastly, to get a function to run you must call it. You can see in the code below, at the very bottom that I have **test(lis)**. This tells python to go ahead and run the function with the input we specify (in this case it is lis)

   ```
   lis = [1, 2,3,4, 5, 7, 9]

   def test(list_):
   # edit 'def' requires tab indentation
   # Using for loop
       for i in list_:
           if (i % 2) != 0:
               save = ("{0} it's odd".format(i))

           else:
               save = ("{0} it's even".format(i))
           print(save)


   test(lis)
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Brack, Thanks for your patience.

1. That has been said before, but, believe it or not, spyder doesn't complain. I will use as mentioned on geeksforgeeks.
2. Understood your explanation. I tried to do this way because I was following a peace of code to make some changes on it. To do that I was trying to understand it first.
3. Got it
   4.That's another thing I can't see in that code.(it works because I use it).

The code I was trying to modify is this: https://gist.github.com/ericrobskyhuntley/0c293113aa75a254237c143e0cf962fa

And what I want is to include  a way to save the processed records when it reaches , for example, multiples of 500.
It will avoid to lose work done if something goes wrong (like it did often)

Once again, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

just I wanted to let you know that the answer you responded too is actually mine, not Moquin. Their name shows up on there too because they edited a spelling error. Also I am creating another answer here to respond to you because I am not yet able to respond in the comment section of other peoples questions. (That is reserved for individuals who have a reputation of 50 or higher on this site). If you liked my last answer, please consider accepting it as the answer by pressing the check mark.

To answer your other question regarding preserving your work, I would consider writing your output to a list. Before, we just printed it out, but if you write it to a list you can access it later in your code. Do so like this:

```
lis = [1, 2,3,4, 5, 7, 9]
empty_lis = []

def test(list_):
# edit 'def' requires tab indentation
# Using for loop
    for i in list_:
        if (i % 2) != 0:
            empty_lis.append(save)
            save = ("{0} it's odd".format(i))


        else:
            empty_lis.append(save)
            save = ("{0} it's even".format(i))

        print(empty_lis)


test(lis)
```

or additionally, you could consider creating a log file to keep track of output and where your script breaks. It will write to a .log file in whatever path you specify.

```
import logging

#create log
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
formatter = logging.Formatter("%(asctime)s:%(levelname)s:%(message)s")
file_handler = logging.FileHandler(r'{insert path here}testlog.log')#iput file path in the curly
#braces and name the lof whatever you want. Just make sure it ends in .log

file_handler.setFormatter(formatter)
logger.addHandler(file_handler)


lis = [1, 2,3,4, 6, 7, 9]
empty_lis = []

def test(list_):
# edit 'def' requires tab indentation
# Using for loop
    for i in list_:
        try:
            if (i % 2) != 0:
                save = ("{0} it's odd".format(i))
                empty_lis.append(save)
            else:
                save = ("{0} it's even".format(i))
                empty_lis.append(save)

            logger.info(" my list is{0}".format(empty_lis)) # this writes to your log
            print(empty_lis)
        except:
            logger.exception("Did not work. See logs for details.")


test(lis)
```

Comment: Brack, sorry for my mistake (I'll get there, just need time :)

Thank you for your double answer!
Could you advise me what solution fits better in the code I mentioned? Whats better "moment" in code to append this operation (take the list "empty_lis" and append to the file that is keeping the results)

Once again, sorry for my mistake and thank you!

Comment: No worries at all Krauss! I am pretty new to this too so every day is a learning experience. I modified the code above (the second one) to show where I would write to the log. the log output will look like this          **2020-03-23 09:20:16,458:INFO: my list is["1 it's odd", "2 it's even", "3 it's odd", "4 it's even", "6 it's even", "7 it's odd", "9 it's odd"]**                                                                                        
all in one line. Hope that answers your question!

Comment: Opss...it did not work in this case (I suppose). The final list should have about 400K items. I need to write it down on a CSV (the results). It's geolocation coordinates with other elements . You have helped me a lot, if it's easy for you I'll thank you a lot if you could modify the code on the link with other strategy. If it's not so simple, let it go, I'll try by myself. Thank in for your time!

Comment: Its no trouble at all. Just curious, but is the geolocation a shapefile? And if so, are you using an application like Arcmap? As far as the code not working, it is probably because of the for loop since the data set is so large (it can be pretty taxing), or it could be bad data...maybe an int where there should be a string. What did the log say at the iteration that it failed at?

Comment: I have it working with no problems. Geolocation is a set of elements that you received via REST API, when you input some address (this case 400K). It response are coordinates (x,y) plus some street information, post code, accuracy, etc.. I use Spyder and the geocoder could be a list of them (ArcGis, google, bing,etc..). It uses a "normalized protocol" created by geopy. https://geopy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/. My problem is some geocoders retrieve some records and after a certain number they shut down connection. If you wrote it you got it if not....restart :). That's why I want to write it.

Comment: after some set of records (something like 500). Resuming, when the loop you see reaches 500 geolocations (records from the input file with geocoder response) It should open the output file and append to all that have been done and keep going. I don't know if my English is clear enough (I'm Portuguese) :)

Comment: haha well you speak better English than I speak Portuguese, that's for sure. II wanted to offer this as a possible solution first because I recently had a colleague use it with great success. The results will  be in a google sheet that you can export to a csv. https://willgeary.github.io/data/2016/11/04/Geocoding-with-Google-Sheets.html  It should be able to handle thousands of records too. Ill also try to come up with a code backup

Comment: Oh man! You're way beyond me!
I thought that google sheets functions (gadgets) were discontinued, and...they were!
Buuuuuttt :) This is so good.
That's what I call an elegant solution!
(thought that I was trying to give you an idea about geocoding AAHAHAHAHA).

Comment: I don't even know how that's possible since google requests an API Key...

Comment: Haha right on, I wish I could take credit for it. Whoever wrote the code for it is amazing. Im really glad I could point you in the right direction and help out!

Comment: Yes, it could help a lot mainly on reverse. Notwithstanding, it only use a single geocoder and if it fails or miss the place, you don't have any other geocoder output to untie. I use the code on the link with 4/5 different geocoders and decide, with similarity algorithms and centroid  calculations, witch one to adopt. But for reverse I'll use it for sure!

Comment: Yeah some geocoders get pretty bad with certain addresses so having more than one to pull on is always an advantage. Having only the google API in this instance is definitely a disadvantage. But the reverse geocoding capability is super nice!

Comment: Hello Brack, do you think you could help on that question? (make changes on the code so it could edit and write the processed records to a file periodically).Thanks!

Comment: Hi Krauss! I would go ahead and submit a seperate new question regarding writing the processed records to a file. Simply because it is not on the topic of the original question and I would not want this question to get flagged and/or deleted. Ill keep my eye out for it if you do